# Merging several ByteArrayOutputStreams into one FileOutputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io

I am splitting up a computation among eight threads and writing the results to a file, as follows:

1a. Each of seven threads processes its input and writes its output to its own `ByteArrayOutputStream`; when the stream closes, the thread `offers` an `<Integer, ByteArrayOutputStream>` to a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, and calls `countDown()` on a `CountDownLatch` (that was initialized to 7).

1b. Concurrently, an eighth thread reads in all of the input data that will be processed on the next iteration.  This thread `awaits` on the `CountDownLatch` when it finishes reading in its data.

2a. When the `CountDownLatch` reaches 0, the eighth thread wakes up, sorts the `ConcurrentinkedQueue` using the `Integer` in the `<Integer, ByteArrayOutputStream>` as the sort key, then iterates through the queue and appends the byte arrays to a file.  (There might be a more efficient way to traverse the list in order without sorting it, but the list only has seven elements in it so the runtime of the sort method is a non-issue.)

2b. Concurrently, the other seven threads process the input that has been prepared for them by the eighth thread.

** This process loops until all data are processed (typically 40-80 iterations).

Each thread processes an equal-sized input chunk (except possibly on the last iteration) of 8mb; each `ByteArrayOutputStream` contains from 1-4 mb, and the output size can't be known ahead of time.  Typically the runtimes of the earliest-completing and latest-completing CPU-bound threads are within 20% of each other.

I am wondering if there is an IO library (or a method in java.io or java.nio that I've missed) that already does something like this - at present the eighth thread (the IO thread) is idle about 75% of the time, but any way I've come up with to alleviate this inefficiency strikes me as being too complicated (and hence too risky in terms of creating deadlocks or data races); for example, I could divide the input into 4 mb chunks and then give two chunks to the seven CPU-bound threads and one chunk to the IO-bound thread which would in theory reduce the IO thread's idle time to 25% (25% on IO, 50% on a 4 mb chunk, 25% idle), but this is a brittle solution that might not port to another CPU (meaning that on another CPU the IO-bound thread might then turn into a bottleneck if e.g. its runtime is 150% that of the CPU-bound threads) - I'd really  like a self-balancing solution so that I don't need to fine-tune the load-balancing by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inefficiency consists in waiting for all 7 outputs to be complete before thread 8 processes any of it. It would be better to run 7 queues instead of one, i.e. one per source thread, and read them in the order necessary. That way when the first queue has any data it is processed immediately, rather than having to wait for the other 6; similarly for queues 2..6. When thread 8 finishes the last queue it can then start producing,or indeed it could be doing that instead of waiting for any specific queue to start producing.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the algorithm as follows:

1. Rather than assigning the input chunks directly to the CPU threads, I instead put the chunks in a `BlockingQueue` from which the CPU threads `poll/take` their work chunks
2. Output is sent to a `ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, ByteArrayOutputStream>`
3. The CPU threads simply loop until canceled.  The IO thread peeks on the `ConcurrentSkipListMap` (using `firstKey`) to see if there is any data to be written (I maintain a counter of what the next key should be to ensure that the output streams are written in order), then it checks the length of the `BlockingQueue` to see if any data needs to be added to it (if `queue.size() < N` then I add N more chunks to it, where N initially equals 12); if it did either or both IO tasks then it loops, otherwise it processes a chunk from the `BlockingQueue` and then loops.

The `BlockingQueue` should not be empty unless the entire input has already been processed by the IO thread - an empty queue indicates that the `queue.size() < N` threshold needs to be raised.  For this reason the CPU threads' logic is

```
while(!cancel) {
    try {
        Input input = queue.poll();
        if(input == null) {
            log.warn("Empty queue");
            input = queue.take();
        }
        process(input);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        cancel = true;
    }
}
```